# How to addclass with timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout, addclass, removeclass

Don't know why it's not working, i think the code is fine - could you tell me what is wrong? I need to add some class after some time interval...

```
$('.main_menu ul li').mouseenter(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(this).children('.sub_menu_main').addClass('opened')
    },200);
});
$('.main_menu ul li').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).children('.sub_menu_main').removeClass('opened')
});
```

Comment: Can you show your html elements too?

Comment: Have you confirmed that your selector statements are returning the correct HTML elements?

Comment: It would be wise to create a JSFiddle (jsfiddle.net) that succinctly reproduces the problem.  Often you will spot the issue yourself when doing that, but at least you can link your question to a full working example of the issue.

Comment: You need to pass a reference to "this" in your timeout since it executes out-of-context from the event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('.main_menu ul li').on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        var self = this; //in scope
        $(self).data('timer', setTimeout(function(){ //new scope
            $(self).children('.sub_menu_main').addClass('opened'); //out of scope
        },200);
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        clearTimeout($(this).data('timer'));
        $(this).children('.sub_menu_main').removeClass('opened');
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice one with the double on events but should it not be self, rather than $(self) ?

Comment: this is good but, now all of .sub_menu_main have opened class and no removing it after mouselaeve...

Comment: @mplungjan: nope, the `$()` wrap the DOM reference in a jQuery object to have access to the `.children()` method. You could use `var that = $(this)` to create a local var that references a jQ object, then you don't need the `$()` in the callback... PS: @adeneo: `self` might not always be the wisest of varnames as it can be a reference to the global object (either window.self or in a worker)

Comment: @ŁukaszBorawski - that's probably because your mouse leaves the element before the timeout adds the class, and that would in fact be the intended way this works. To make sure that does'nt happen you would have to clear the timeout in the mouseleave function.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem - I tend to referrence the DOM element in my variables, as it's easier to wrap the element in jQuery than to get the DOM element back, and I tend to use the native DOM element quite a lot. I've never had problems with `self`, and inside a worker you would'nt have access to the DOM anyway, so that point is kinda mute!

Comment: is there any possible to add timeout on mouseenter action, if my cursor is more than 3 seconds on element the function is fire up, when it's less nothing happens?

Comment: @ŁukaszBorawski - Yep, changed my answer !

Comment: Thanks. I did not get the unwrapping and re-wrapping

Comment: @adeneo: the `self` argument isn't a very solid one, but I just like to avoid confusion. When looking at code using `self`, some ppl might assume that it's a reference to the global scope, whereas `that` tells you to look for the "nearest" `this` reference. As for referencing `this` using variables: I coulnd't agree more, but that was just to clarify a couple of things for @mplungjan

Comment: it's work perfectly but, now when i enter at the next 'li', everything returns to the start state

Answer (score 2):

I believe `this` isn't referencing what you think it does in that scope. You should try storing a reference to this in your outer scope, and then access the hovered element through that reference instead:

```
$('.main_menu ul li').mouseenter(function(){
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(that).children('.sub_menu_main').addClass('opened')
    },200);
});
```

Comment: @mplungjan Not sure what you are asking? `this` refer to the DOM element in the callback, as far as I can remember, therefor you need to pass it to the jQuery-function prior to calling any methods.

Comment: the other comment answered it. I would consider `var $that=$(this)` and use $that instead of wrapping something that used to be a jQuery object in a jQuery object to get it back